# How do I replace the seats and springs in this Delta kitchen faucet?

Tags: repair, faucet

My Delta kitchen faucet has gotten really difficult to turn off. It will drip unless you turn it off just right.
[image: kitchen faucet]
I am trying to take it apart and replace the seats and springs. But this is as far as I can get. I tried loosening the brass nut but it would not budge even with a 12-in pipe wrench.

How do I take this thing apart to replace the seats?

Answer (score 3):

Betting that's a cartridge replacement, not "seats" - regardless, sounds like a cheater bar (wrench extender for more leverage) or a bigger wrench (a pipe wrench is the wrong type of wrench given you have machined flats for use with a socket, or an open-end, or adjustable wrench. Pipe wrenches are for round things.) Heat may also help, but don't go nuts and melt the plastic parts. Moderate impact (tapping wrench with hammer) may also help get it started.

[The instructions](https://media.deltafaucet.com/MandI/64211%20Rev%20A.pdf) don't indicate anything funky like left-hand threading.

I trust you've turned off the water below the sink and relieved pressure already? It can get messy in a hurry if you forget that step.